# Standalone CM 11 style lockscreen

Tags: gratis, android, lockscreen

I'm a big fan of the CyanogenMod11 / Trebuchet lockscreen - It lets you add shortcuts to the unlocking ring so you can touch and swipe in that direction to directly launch an app. However switching all of my devices to CM is not an option - I like the nearly stock android 4.4 on my moto G, and the best I can do for my HTC One V is android 4.2. Both run the google now launcher.

[image]

My requirements are pretty simple:

1. It needs to standalone, and I need to be able to use whatever launcher I want with it
2. It should work on Android 4.2 or better
3. It plays nice with the google now launcher
4. It allows me to add apps to the lockscreen like what you see there
5. It's Free - I can't buy apps from the google play store at the moment.

I've tried bazooka (loved the lock screen, hated the themes) , but a perfect answer wouldn't hinge on another launcher for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Next launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.next&hl=en) isn't quite *visually* the same, but it does what I need it to do.

[image]

It lets me pin 5 apps to the bottom. I need to turn off the stock lock screen but its fine for me. It does *limited* on lock screen notifications. It also has a built in flashlight app (which is what I wanted for it for anyway).

Answer (score 3):

The approach I know of needs your phone to be rooted. Firstly you have to install the Xposed Framework, which can be obtained from [here](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer).

Then you will have to install GravityBox, GravityBox is for near AOSP roms so it will not work well with MIUI and other heavily customized ROMs(including CM,AOKP). You can download the GravityBox apk from inside of Xposed Installer or from [here](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer).(The one I linked to is the Jelly Bean version of it, [this](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.kitkat.gravitybox) is the KitKat version).

You can then change the unlock ring targets.

[image]